# Storing data in Redis and/or relational database

Tags: relational-database, redis

I have about 50,000 json objects that I am storing in Redis.
This works well for the main use case of finding an object by its unique key.

I now have to add a feature to search for objects based on complex queries based on the objects data. For example all items with an author like 'lex', published between 2011-03-01 and 2012-01-12 with over 5 items in stock.

With SQL this is simple.
I don't know Redis very well but have not seen any thing like this for it.

So I was thinking to have a small relational database where I would store the Redis keys and the data I need to search on. When a complex query is needed I hit the SQL and get a set of key to pull out of Redis.

The data I have changes infrequently and I will know when and what has changed. So I can import the data into the rmdb and Redis when it updated.

Is this approach a good idea?

Comment: Why not switching to relational DB entirely? 50k objects is nothing, any DB will handle that.

Comment: And if you still want to store JSON, I recommend [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org).

Comment: I have the data in json format, I am feeding it out to other programs that want it in json format. Seemed odd to have a db map it down to tables then rebuild it back up into json when it was just a key value lookup at the time.

Comment: use mongodb, it stores JSON and it has indexes.

Comment: Sounds interesting I will take a look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a document database (one of NoSQL favors).

As @Sergio suggested, [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/) is one of them. There are others ([CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) and more) and you must check to see which fits best for you. They differ in performance, replication abilities, stability, maturity, support etc.

- [List of document stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Document_store) in Wikipedia
- http://nosql-database.org/ - Look under *Document Store*

Comment: I have now had the chance to prototype MongoDB, for this particular use case it does seem a much better fit than my idea.

Answer (score 5):

Are queries dynamic? Because you can build structures in Redis do queries like what you describe. Use Ordered sets for time for example, have another ordered set for inventory numbers, query and intersect them. If you know exatly what searches you want to run you can make Redis do it very fast for you. If queries change all the time (playign with data, analyzing it etc) then it is not a really good solution.

So for storing something

```
set key object1

zadd time_set object1.time object1
zadd inventory_set object1.inventory object1
```

to query time and inventory

```
zrangebyscore time_set min_time max_time
zrangebyscore inventory_set min_inventory max_inventory

Then you intersect them yourself, since results are just ids this is really fast. Once you intersected them just do an

mget item1, item 2...
```

In general Redis works really well when you know exactly what queries you will be running on it.